# Pandas Dataframe: Inplace vs assigning to same dataframe again

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

Below are the two ways actually to drop a column from a `pandas` dataframe.

By using inplace parameter.

```
user.drop(['gender'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

By assigning to same variable again.

```
user = user.drop('gender' , axis = 1)
```

Which one is more efficient if working with large datasets( Data file with size in GB )?

Comment: The second approach creates a _copy_  of the dataframe. If the dataframe is really large, making a copy may be slow.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use inplace parameter.

```
user.drop(['gender'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

if you doesn't use inplce, your IDE have to replace data-frame itself and it is not efficient.